# How can find record with odd id in database by lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to know is there any way to find record with odd id in Database by using `lambda expression`  in c#?

I try it but it is not working !!

```
 GoogleEntities db = new GoogleEntities();
List<tbl_search> _oddSearchList = db.tbl_search.Where(c => (c.id / 2) == 0).tolist();
```

How can do it?

Comment: use % 2 instead of / 2, also == 1 if you want odd, not even

Comment: Thanks @Atomosk for your fast and true answer

Answer (score 3):

I think you need this

```
c => (c.id % 2) == 0 // modulus operator instead of divide operator.
```

But again, this would return an even, because ID fully divided by 2 is even. You need this

```
c => (c.id % 2) != 0
```

To get the odd number.

So, after this, your code would be this one

```
List<tbl_search> _oddSearchList = db.tbl_search.Where(
                                  c => (c.id % 2) != 0
                                  ).tolist();
```

Comment: Personally I'd want to just double check the SQL translation of this to make sure that the modulus is being performed at a DB level and it's not pulling everything into memory! But then I'm paranoid ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the module operator `%`, which checks for the rest of a division.

```
List<tbl_search> _oddSearchList = db.tbl_search.Where(c => (c.id % 2) == 1).tolist();
```

Also check if the result is 1 instead of 0. If the rest is 0, then the id is divisible by 2 and therefor EVEN.